# Which radio button is selected in a button group

Tags: java, radio-button, buttongroup

What can I do to get which radiobutton is selected on a buttongroup without doing this:

```
if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
    //...
}

if (jRadioButton2.isSelected()) {
    //...
}

if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {
    //...
}

if (jRadioButton4.isSelected()) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darryl's [Select Button Group](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/09/select-button-group/) has a getSelectedButton() method.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the ButtonModel for the selected button via the [getSelection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#getSelection%28%29)() method of ButtonGroup.  I don't know how you can avoid conditionally branching on the selected button though, unless you have some sort of ancillary data structure mapping from ButtonModel to actions to perform, for instance.  If you had that, then you could just fire the action based on the returned ButtonModel.

Comment: how do I convert the button model which is being returned. Into something like jRadioButton1 or jRadioButton2?

Comment: You can't convert it; that model is used to power the JRadioButton.  It's a model view controller separation.  What are you trying to accomplish, and I can tell you how to do it.

Comment: Trying to: get the currently selected radiobutton. Or some way to let you know which one is it and according to that execute different lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question was posted long back. Anyway, we can use the setActioncommand function. while creating the radio button, setActionCommand could be invoked to set the action command value, which could be used to refer to the radio button that was selected.

`jRadioButton1.setActionCommand("jRadioButton1");
jRadioButton2.setActionCommand("jRadioButton2")
.
.
String button_name = ((JToggleButton.ToggleButtonModel)button_group.getSelection()).getActionCommand();`

Answer (score 0):

ButtonGroup class does not provide a method to identify the currently selected button (inherited from AbstractButton) in the group if that is your intention. It only has clearSelection() method to clear the selected state of all buttons in the group (with exception for JButton and JMenuItem which don't have select/deselect button state).

One solution I can think of is to use a special variable or field (AbstractButton, JRadioButton or JRadioButtonMenuItem if it is in a menu item) to identify which one is currently selected by updating it inside each AbstractButton's action listener method (make sure to validate user clicks since it can be triggered more than once!). Use the variable (by typecasting it - for AbstractButton only) in other method(s).

Other than that, nope...you will need to do conditional branching.

Answer (score 0):

For dealing with a button group bg, you can get the buttons by calling the button group's getElements() method, and using that as the parameter for the Collections.list() method, just save the result in an arraylist. From there it is relatively simple to retrieve the correct button.

```
ArrayList<AbstractButton> arl = Collections.list(bg.getElements());
for (AbstractButton ab : arl) {
    JRadioButton jrb = (JRadioButton) ab;
    if (jrb.isSelected()) {
        return jrb;
    }
}
```

Comment: add some description to it